# URL Rewrite Including Trailing Slash If Not Present

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got this `RewriteRule` to work.

```
RewriteBase /my/path/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my/path/index.php [L]
```

So URLs with a trailing slash work. `http://localhost/my/path/foo/bar/`
The problem is that URLs without the trailing slash will break relative links. Plus it dosen't look good.

This reaches the maximum number of internal redirects.

```
RewriteRule ^/my/path/(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R]
RewriteRule . /my/path/index.php [L]
```

And this will do... `http://localhost/my/path/index.php/bar/`

```
RewriteRule . /my/path/index.php
RewriteRule ^/my/path/(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R,L]
```

Any Ideas or solutions?

Comment: The `^/my/path` pattern shouldn't match in `.htaccess`. This is in the virtual host configuration file?

Comment: @azz The actual path is more like `/sandbox/htaccess/` if that changes anything.

Comment: No, it's that in `.htaccess` the pattern that `RewriteRule` matches is the path stripped of the `RewriteBase` prefix (`/my/path/foo` → `foo`). So in your second ruleset `^/my/path` can't match anything and the second rule gives the loop. (Just a tangentially related fact.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusing feature of `mod_rewrite` is that, **after an internal redirect**, even one qualified with `[L]`, **the entire set of rules is processed again** from the beginning.

So you redirect a nonexistent path to `index.php`, but then the rules for adding a slash kick in and you don't get the result you want.

In your case you simply need to put the file nonexistence condition on both of the redirect rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /my/path/index.php [L]
```

Or maybe move this condition to the top of the file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]   # redirect to same location to stop processing

RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^ /my/path/index.php [L]
```

There's also an undocumented trick to stop processing after an internal redirect which should make more complex rulesets easier to write – using the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is set after an internal redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .  # <-- that's a dot there
RewriteRule ^ - [L]   # redirect to same location to stop processing

RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^ /my/path/index.php [L]
```