# Mod_rewrite so that /abc goes to index.php?name=abc

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I need to have URLs fitting this criteria:

www.domain.com/abc

rewritten to be:

www.domain.com/index.php?name=abc

I can do it where the last letter(s) are fixed like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ index.php?name=$1
```

which means www.domain.com/abc.htm would go to www.domain.com/index.php?name=abc

but I need it to not have the .htm (or anything after the abc)

Can this be done? I've spent some time trying to find the solution but so far without success.

Thanks in anticipation.

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1`

I am not completely sure on your criteria though, this will send everything to the PHP script.

If you only want to rewrite the first part of a path ie.  /abc but not abc/def or abc/ I can change it for you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did try this but the name get variable has index.php rather than abc

Comment: Try changing it to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [L]` and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, no difference I'm afraid. It still gives index.php in the get variable.

Comment: After the redirect it rewrites `index.php` again. You need a `RewriteCond` that will exclude `index.php`, or maybe any existing files.

Comment: I figured that was the case. Can you give me an example? I've tried all sorts but still without success.

Comment: E.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120866/url-rewrite-including-trailing-slash-if-not-present).

Comment: Thanks @aaz but I'm getting more and more confused now! I'm guessing it's a simple line I need but am going round in circles.

Comment: @Jon – Basically anything that will prevent `index.php` being rewritten as `index.php?name=abc`. Could be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` like in that question, which stops rewrites for any existing files. Could be just `RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php$`, which stops it just for `index.php`.